# SignalR-based online support system for Asp.Net MVC website

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, signalr, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an Asp.Net MVC 5 website. I want to add a component to the website which allows us to have an online support system. I've seen a lot of websites that have this. Users click on a link, a popup (or another page) opens, then the user chats with the support in a session. Is there something like this (open source proffered) for Asp.Net MVC. Ideally I want this to be implemented with SignalR.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what are you looking for

Tutorial: [ASP.NET MVC 5 + SignalR + Chat](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20-and-mvc-5)

And [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/562023/Asp-Net-SignalR-Chat-Room) you are an complete project. Another good [tutorial](http://tech.pro/tutorial/1491/chat-application-with-signalr-and-aspnet-mvc-4), step by step, and with code in [GitHub](https://github.com/Sampath-Lokuge/SignalRChatApp). As you can see, searching a bit we can find a lot of projects already implemented.

If you want robust complete solution take a look at [JabbR](https://github.com/JabbR/JabbR). I do not know something better for free using these specific technologies.

Comment: Thank you very much. However, I remember reading the first article you posted to learn about SignalR and the 2nd one is basically a lot like the first one. The problem is, none of them are actually a finished product to use in a real-world website. I just thought maybe there is one (like a nuget package).

Comment: Also, you might ask why they aren't finished? There are numerous security concerns. Furthermore, I need a lot more feature (for example a queue and a timeout to show how much the user must wait in the queue, or maybe logging all the chat sessions for future access and referring)... The tutorials you posted are **for sure** really helpful but no where near what I want.

Comment: I understand, I updated my answer. Take a look at JabbR, I didn't try myself but it has 905 starts and 412 Forks in Github, so it cannot be bad.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's not a support system but if I can't find a support system, this is a very good second option to start with.

Answer (score 0):

For a complete chat solution that uses SignalR, check out ChatJS:

http://chatjs.net/

Comment: http://chatjs.net/ is using a DemoAdapter with robot repeat what you are typing , in this project I see the SignalRAdapter but I don't know how to use it in ASP.NET server code. For example how to fetch the login users and pass to this adapter. If you know please show me. Thanks!